# Convex function at four points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Is it true that for any $x<y$, $$f(x)+f(y)\leq f(x-1)+f(y+1)?$$

Looking at graphs of convex functions, this is always true. But I don't see how it can follow from the definition of convex function
$$f(tx+(1-t)y)\le tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$$
for $0<t<1$.

Comment: You may see this [$f(x)+f(x+y+z)≥f(x+y)+f(x+z)$ for convex functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448345/fxfxyz-geq-fxyfxz-for-convex-functions?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set $t = \frac{y-x+1}{y-x+2}$ we see that
$$x = t(x-1) + (1-t)(y+1)\quad\text{and}\quad y = (1-t)(x-1) + t(y+1),$$
therefore
$$f(x) \leq tf(x-1)+(1-t)f(y+1)\quad\text{and}\quad f(y) \leq (1-t)f(x-1) + tf(y+1).$$